# Animate on Class Add/ Remove

Tags: reactjs

I'm adding/ removing a class based on a state change (bootstrap col classes that I cannot modify). How can this transition get animated in ReactJs?

```
<div className={this.state.is_drawer_open ? 'col-xs-8' : 'col-xs-12'}>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As bootstrap's cols are based on CSS width with percentage value, You can use normal CSS transitions to animate the width change.

In your CSS add a class with transition:

```
.animateTransition {
    transition: width 1s;
}
```

Apply the class to your element:

```
<div className={ `animateTransition ${this.state.is_drawer_open ? 'col-xs-8' : 'col-xs-12'}` }>
```

Comment: This would be my approach, I've put together a simple example here: http://jsbin.com/qacahevohe/edit?html,js,output